# Onclick reset current position of element to the one that is set in css

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bubble").click(function(){
        // $("input").append(" <b>Appended text</b>");
        var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var y = (parseInt(x, 10) || 0) + 1;
        x = y;
        console.log(x);
        $('#input').val(x);
        var currentPosition = document.getElementById("aDiv").offsetTop;
        console.log(currentPosition);
        document.getElementById("aDiv").style.top === 370;
    });
    $(".btn-danger").click(function(){

        $('#input').val("");
    });

});


$(document).ready(function(){
 console.log(document.getElementById("aDiv").offsetTop);
 var e = document.getElementById("aDiv");
 var s = 1;
 setInterval(function(){
     var eLeftPos = e.offsetTop;
     // console.log(eLeftPos);
     e.style.top = (eLeftPos - s) + 'px';

 }, 200);

})
```

```css
.bg{
 height: 400px;
 background-color: #FFF1F1;
 /*display: inline-block;*/
 position: relative;
}

.bubble{
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #24E93E;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Game</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-xs-3 btnDiv">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">STOP</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">PLAY</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6  bg main-block">
    <div class="bubble" id="aDiv"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3 score-place">
    <input id="input" type="text" name="" placeholder="">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I have a div, and a little round, which is going up, when I click on it, there is score on right, now I need to also add, on lick reset it`s position ( it is position: absolute and top: 370 or bottom: 0). 
I have tried`document.getElementById("aDiv").style.top === 370;
        document.getElementById("aDiv").style.bottom === 0;` 
but there is no effect

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, it was

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bubble").click(function(){
        // $("input").append(" <b>Appended text</b>");
        var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var y = (parseInt(x, 10) || 0) + 1;
        x = y;
        console.log(x);
        $('#input').val(x);
        var currentPosition = document.getElementById("aDiv").offsetTop;
        console.log(currentPosition);
        document.getElementById("aDiv").style.top = "370px";
        // document.getElementById("aDiv").style.bottom === 0;
    });
    $(".btn-danger").click(function(){

        $('#input').val("");
    });

});


$(document).ready(function(){
 console.log(document.getElementById("aDiv").offsetTop);
 var e = document.getElementById("aDiv");
 var s = 1;
 setInterval(function(){
     var eLeftPos = e.offsetTop;
     // console.log(eLeftPos);
     e.style.top = (eLeftPos - s) + 'px';

 }, 200);

})
```

```css
.bg{
 height: 400px;
 background-color: #FFF1F1;
 /*display: inline-block;*/
 position: relative;
}

.bubble{
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #24E93E;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Game</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-xs-3 btnDiv">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">STOP</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">PLAY</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6  bg main-block">
    <div class="bubble" id="aDiv"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3 score-place">
    <input id="input" type="text" name="" placeholder="">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to change "===" to "="